# jQuery dom traversal nested tables

Tags: jquery, traversal

I'm trying to map the tabledata of a row from within another table but I'm not sure how to get there.

I tried things like:

```
$('.order_info .active').closest('tr').prev('tr').children('td').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

$(this).find('.order_info .active').closest('tr').prev('tr').children('td').map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
    }).get();
```

but with no luck.

This is how the DOM looks like and from where to where I need to go.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the html structure?

Comment: Try parents and not closest

Comment: @MikeB: No, it wouldn't.

Comment: `$(this).closest(".order_info").prev()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the row containing the table that row is in via `.parent().closest("tr")` (need the `.parent` because otherwise it would match the row you're in). Then you get the previous one via `.prev()`.

If your starting point isn't the actual `tr` but something *inside* it, then `.closest("tr").parent().closest("tr").prev()`. For instance, if you want to handle a click on a cell in that row:

```
$(this).closest("tr").parent().closest("tr").prev();
```

If the previous row isn't always the one you want, you can scan for `.event` via `.prevAll(".even").first()`.

Links:

- [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent)
- [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest)
- [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev)
- [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll)
- [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first)

Comment: `.closest('tr').parent().closest('tr).prev()` worked! I haven't really used `parent()` before so wasn't sure how to do this.